# Failed to initialize tracing backend

Tags: java

When I try to use Java Flight Recorder I get an error stating that Java "Failed to initialize tracing backend" when starting Java.

My command line is:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-XX:StartFlightRecording=compress=true,delay=10000,maxage=1440,filename=test.jfr
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,dist=true,loglevel=trace,settings=profile.jfc,dumponexit=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java Flight Recorder has dreadful documentation and error reporting. The error could be for a number of reasons. It seems that if you have more than one mistake in your command line - no errors will be reported correctly.

Possible mistakes include:

- Mistyping a parameter. I had typed dist=true instead of disk=true.
- Entering a number for a time.

Although the documentation says:

> maxage=time Specifies the maximum age (in minutes) of disk data for default recording.

what it actually means is that you must specify a unit. For example 30m for half an hour or 30s for half a minute. This applies to other times too:

> delay=time Specifies the delay (in milliseconds) between the Java
>   application launch time and the start of the recording.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is written when `VirtualMachineError` instance is thrown when starting java, in cases such as when java agent fails to be loaded. JDK (up to 9) is not very desriptive about what went wrong.

- JDK 7 writes just:

  > Error occurred during initialization of VM
  >
  > Failed to start tracing backend.
  >
  > Java Result: 1
- JDK 8 is a bit more descriptive it can point to a class that's wrong, adding to JDK's 7 output something like:

  > [jfr][WARN ][2.293] JFR initialization attempt failed.
  >
  > [java] [jfr][WARN ][2.293] org.somepackage.SomeClass
- JDK 9 is what can really help here, as it writes the `VirtualMachineError`'s message with stack trace such as:

  > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.somepackage.SomeClass